# GSON Pretty Print problemLooking For Solution

Tags: gson, pretty-print

Hi guys i need some help!

My Current Pretty Print Gson Object :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

My Current Output is :

```
{
  "YYYY": "ZZZZ",
  "FFFFFFFFF": [
    {
      "AAAAAA": 1
    },
    {
      "BBBBB": 1
    },
    {
      "CCCCCCC": 2
    },
    {
      "TTTTTT": 10
    },
    {
      "PPPPPPPP": 66
    },
    {
      "SSSSSSS": 99
    }
  ]
}
```

My Desired output is :

```
{
  "YYYY": "ZZZZ",
  "FFFFFFFFFFFF":
     [
        { "AAAAAA": 1},
        { "BBBBBB": 1},
        { "CCCCCC": 2},
        { "TTTTTT": 10},
        { "PPPPPP": 66},
        { "SSSSSS": 99 }
     ]
}
```

Thanks very much in advance! trying out this for some good json application that makes me go nuts!! Would appreciate it if someone renders some help!

Answer (score 1):

From the Gson [guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Compact-Vs.-Pretty-Printing-for-JSON-Output-Format)

> If you like to use the Pretty Print feature, you must configure your
>   Gson instance using the GsonBuilder.  The JsonFormatter  is not
>   exposed through our public API, so the client is unable to configure
>   the default print settings/margins for the JSON output.  **For now, we
>   only provide a default JsonPrintFormatter that has default line length
>   of 80 character, 2 character indentation, and 4 character right
>   margin.**

This means that with Gson, cannot reach your goal this way.

The only thing you can do is to extend `JsonWriter` class and do proper customizations (assuming that you have original object to generate the object). However if you need to format only once, there are a lot of online formatter on the net.